# Python removing/clearing items in database

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm just starting with Python and I have to create small a database. I use code that is too complicated for me and I've got some problems.
Structure of database is following:

```
def load_data():
    global base
    global magazine_base
    magazine_base = shelve.open('magazine_base')
    if magazine_base.has_key('base'):
        base = magazine_base['base']
        if not base:
            base = []
    else:
        base = []
        magazine_base['base'] = base

#####Entries are made by:


base += [{
            'name': name, 
            'quantity': int(quantity),
            'price': float(price)
        }]
        magazine_base['base'] = base
        magazine_base.close()

##########And the problem is that the function to clear it all is not working properly, sometimes it doesn't remove, sometimes error, and sometimes data is cleared after restart.

def removeall():
    global magazine_base
    global base
    magazine_base.clear()
    magazine_base.items()

######For the single entry it works perfect, maybe somehow modify it to clear all the entries?

def remove():
    global base
    global magazine_base
    load_data()
    name=raw_input('Give name of a product: ')
    our_product = False
    for elem in base:
        if elem['name'] == name:
            del base[base.index(elem)]
            print 'Product deleted from the list'
            our_product = True
        if not our_product:
        print "Error! No such product in the magazine!"
    magazine_base['base'] = base
    magazine_base.close()
```

Comment: please clearly explain in detail the problem you are facing. Your description does not say anything about the problem.

Comment: Sorry I put comments between code, function removeall is simply not working as it should, it should clear base immediately instead it sometimes don't do it, sometimes after restarting. I have no idea why

Answer (score 0):

In the `removeall` function, you clear `magazine_base`, but not `base`; depending on which function you call next, the entries that are still in `base` may get reinstated.

What you probably want to do is to re-initialise it to an empty list, as you do in `load_data`:

```py
def removeall():
    global magazine_base
    global base
    magazine_base.clear()
    base = []
    magazine_base['base'] = base
```